# jQuery lightbox(featherlight) not working with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using [featherlight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) lightweight jQuery lightbox plugin but I don't understand how to load lightbox using with click event as I am not good with jQuery codes.

Here is my code work:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1">Load Lightbox</a>
<button id="openbox">Load Lightbox on click event</button>

<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
    <h2>Delete Item</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <strong>Are you Sure?</strong>
            <br>blubblub?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn_gray no text_none" id="close_button">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn_red text_none">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#openbox", function() {
    jQuery('.lightbox').featherlight();
});
```

JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/18/](http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/18/)

***Comment Reply:***

***But what If I want to display lightbox with logical condition like:***

```
var checkedCount = $('.chkAssets:checked').length; // Getting some counts

if(checkedCount == 1){
    // Load lightbox if condition is match
}
```

I hoping someone guide me proper way.

Thanks.

Comment: provided fiddle link is working..

Comment: @Gowri Sorry its my mistake. I am updating my jsfiddle.

Comment: @Gowri Hi. I have updated fiddle. I want to open lightbox on button click event not default anchor link. Here is my fiddle link `http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/18/`

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/19/

Comment: @Mr.Happy check Kartikeya link that's working.Added the lightbox attribute(data-featherlight) to button filed.

Comment: @Kartikeya Can you please check this updated fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/18/`

Comment: yes check her link and delete all javascript / jquery its useless there

Comment: the fiddle link you have provided is not updated one???

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/19/  i think this is what you want.

Comment: @Mr.Happy I think it's not correct way. But check this . http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/24/

Comment: @Gowri Please, dpnt do that again.

Comment: @Mr.Happy Look @ my answer, I've updated too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     $.featherlight('#fl1');
```

Pay attention that the lightbox has id "fl1"

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/26/

and here with if else example
http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/27/

Comment: the answer you provided is already provided in my fiddle link in above comments.

Comment: @Kartikeya Yes i saw it too late, sorry!

Comment: Hi. I having some condition in my logic and I different lightbox display logic wise. Check my question I have updated with bold text. Thanks.

Comment: For example If `checkedCount == 1` display first lightbox and `checkedCount > 1` display second lightbox.

Comment: display too different buttons ?

Comment: I have to use only one button. On button click event I am getting check box counts. If checkedCount == 1 display first lightbox and If checkedCount > 1 display second lightbox. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Happy Look @ the new fiddle please

Comment: @Webice Thanks for your great support. Its working for me :) Thumbs up for you :)